# Codeigniter : Fetch Data into Canvas js

Tags: php, codeigniter, charts

i have some problem to fetch data into my chart using [Canvas js](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/).
So, i have result json_encode() like this :

```
[{"jumlah_berita":2,"nama_kategori":"Music"},{"jumlah_berita":1,"nama_kategori":"Sport"},{"jumlah_berita":1,"nama_kategori":"Agama"},{"jumlah_berita":0,"nama_kategori":"Teknologi"},{"jumlah_berita":1,"nama_kategori":"Pendidikan"},{"jumlah_berita":0,"nama_kategori":"Cinta"},{"jumlah_berita":0,"nama_kategori":"coba test"}]
```

And my chart like This[image: chartbefore]

I want implement my chart Like this, how can i make this ?
[image: After Chart]

#### It's my Code to create **CHART**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var jumlahBerita = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
            animationEnabled: true,
            theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
            title: {
                text: "Jumlah Berita(per Kategori)"
            },

            data: [{
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: [{
                        y: 3,
                        label: "< 30 Tahun"
                    },
                    {
                        y: 25,
                        label: "30-40 Tahun"
                    },
                    {
                        y: 5,
                        label: "> 40 Tahun"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        });
        jumlahBerita.render();

    }
</script>
```

> The problem is when i'm place data `json_encode()` in `dataPoints` like this:

```
dataPoints:<?= $tampil_kategori ?>
```

My chart just render blank white

Can you help me with this ?

Thank's

> If you need my Controller and Model to fetch `json_encode()`
>
> #### Controller

```
$data['tampil_kategori'] = json_encode($this->home->getAllKategori(), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

#### Model

```
public function getAllKategori()
    {
        $this->db->select('jumlah_berita,nama_kategori');
        return $this->db->get('tb_kategori')->result();
    }
```

> Oh i forgot , can i'm modified the result `json_encode()` from :

```
[{"jumlah_berita":2,"nama_kategori":"Music"},{"jumlah_berita":1,"nama_kategori":"Sport"},{"jumlah_berita":1,"nama_kategori":"Agama"},{"jumlah_berita":0,"nama_kategori":"Teknologi"},{"jumlah_berita":1,"nama_kategori":"Pendidikan"},{"jumlah_berita":0,"nama_kategori":"Cinta"},{"jumlah_berita":0,"nama_kategori":"coba test"}]
```

To this ?

```
[
{1,"Pendidikan,}
{2,"Sport"},
{3,"Agama"},
]
```

Comment: Please, format your code and structure your question to complete it. It is too hard to read right now. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

use **JSON.parse** if you're passing encoded data.

```
var tampil_kategori = '<?php  echo $tampil_kategori; ?>';
var newdataPoints = JSON.parse(tampil_kategori);

dataPoints : newdataPoints
```

Comment: Not work for me, my chart not render just blank white.

Comment: I dont know this chart plugin [Canvas JS](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/) the `y` and `label` i think it's absolute / cant be modified